# Create python console in my GUI application

Tags: python, user-interface, console

I have a GUI application and want it to be able to create a console with python interpreter in it. I want to redirect STDOUT and STDERR to it and export the namespace of my application there.

What's the simplest way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Tkinter Shell to GUI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665566/python-tkinter-shell-to-gui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at the source code for [IDLE](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/idlelib) which contains this functionality and is released as part of CPython. Specifically, [PyShell.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/idlelib/PyShell.py) looks to be relevant. You could probably just import idlelib.PyShell as a module and use its functionality.