# Show command line results in Tkinter text widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, stdout

I want the output of a Python script in a Tkinter text widget instead of in the command line. I have this script from https://stackoverflow.com/a/665598/3524043:

```
from Tkinter import *
import subprocess as sub
p = sub.Popen('./Scripts/Speedtest.py',stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.PIPE, shell=True)
output, errors = p.communicate()

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()
text.insert(END, output)
root.mainloop()
```

I've added `shell=true` at the subprocess, cause I had a `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`.

When I run the program there's only an empty text widget.

> Edited with a better solution:

Import the script and call the objects

```
from Tkinter import *
from Speedtest import ping_speed, download_speed, upload_speed

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, ping_speed)
text.insert(END, download_speed)
text.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: why are you running a Python script in Python as a subprocess?

Comment: I thought this was the correct way. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can just import `Speedtest.py` as a module to your main one and call the objects you want, instead of complicating life.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ you're right! Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5136686/7032856) you can do it fairly simply with the below code:

```
import subprocess           # required for redirecting stdout to GUI

try:
    import Tkinter as tk    # required for the GUI python 2
except:
    import tkinter as tk    # required for the GUI python 3


def redirect(module, method):
    '''Redirects stdout from the method or function in module as a string.'''
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "-c",
        "import " + module + ";" + module + "." + method + "()"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = proc.communicate()[0]
    return out.decode('unicode_escape')

def put_in_txt():
    '''Puts the redirected string in a text.'''
    txt.insert('1.0', redirect(module.get(), method.get()))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()

    txt = tk.Text(root)
    module = tk.Entry(root)
    method = tk.Entry(root)
    btn = tk.Button(root, text="Redirect", command=put_in_txt)

    #layout
    txt.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    module.pack(fill='both', expand=True, side='left')
    btn.pack(fill='both', expand=True, side='left')
    method.pack(fill='both', expand=True, side='left')

    root.mainloop()
```

given that the module is in the *same* directory. The code returns console output of a method or a function(rightmost entry) in a module(leftmost entry) as a string. It then puts that string in a [Text](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) field.

---

See this answer for [Returning *all* methods/functions from a script without explicitly passing method names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48039105/7032856).