# How do I embed windows command prompt into tkinter application?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I am trying to embed windows command prompt into my GUI so that the user can see what they have selected in the GUI window instead of having to keep the command prompt window open as well.

I have searched for this quite extensively on Google and I haven't got anything conclusive yet.

Comment: If your program has a GUI, why would the user need to keep a command windows open to see what they have selected?

Comment: I need the output of everything to be redirected from the command prompt to the GUI so that the user can see what is happening.

Comment: Have you read [Redirect command line results to a tkinter GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665566/redirect-command-line-results-to-a-tkinter-gui)?

Comment: Yes, and it did not help

Comment: Hmm, if the user has to do that to see what they've selected, it doesn't sound like you truly have what most would call an application with a GUI. Regardless, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977473/display-the-output-of-the-program-on-gui-with-tkinter) to the question [Display the output of the program on GUI with tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977473/display-the-output-of-the-program-on-gui-with-tkinter) which might help.

Comment: create `subprocess`, get text from `stdout` and display in GUI's widget  - embed window command prompt works this way. But it seems you already read about it and it didn't help you.