# Why the output of an external Python Script isn't displaying into my Python Tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I hope you are doing great this new year,
I am creating a GUI program (Python3 Tkinter) which displays the output of another python script into a big entry.

**Situation:**
My GUI has only 1 button which execute this command:
`python external_python_script.py -h`

However I want the whole output of this command execution to be displayed into an entry, and **not** into the CMD.

**So far this is my solution, but not effective:**

`command_textbox = os.system(python external_python_script.py -h) #simply execute the code in brackets`

`script_output.insert('1.0',command_textbox) #the whole output of the script will be displayed in this entry`

**What happened when I did this?**

In the GUI program, when I pressed the button, into the Entry it is displayed only this `0`

*Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!*

Comment: ***`0`***: From `os.system` you get only the return code, use [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instead.

Comment: `os.system` returns the exit status of the command it executed, not some output. Rather than calling your python script this way, couldn't you rather import it?

Comment: Take a look at the code in the `errorwindow3k.py` module in my answer to the question [Display the output of the program on GUI with tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977473/display-the-output-of-the-program-on-gui-with-tkinter) It uses `subprocess.Popen` instead of `os.system` (as @stovfl suggests).

Comment: @ThierryLathuille: Executing a non-tkinter script that prints its output from one using it to create a GUI (however that is done) would likely _not_ display the output in the GUI.

Comment: Clearly not, but the parts of the script that produce the output could be used in a cleaner way

Comment: Thank you guys so much, I finally solved my problem. Yeah, subprocess is the solution. Here is my code which solves it:


```final_command = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True)```


```output_box.insert('1.0',final_command)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for helping me, Subprocess is the solution. So I put only these 2 lines of code and I got the solution I wanted:

`final_command = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True)`

`output_box.insert('1.0',final_command)`