# How to show console window output result in tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter, console

I like to show console window output result in tkinter window. How to do this?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkjyb.png)

[I want Output Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wA2F.png)

Here is my sample code:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.ttk import *
window = Tk()
space = ""
window.title(80*space + "Addition and Subtraction")
window.geometry("800x600+100+100")
n1 = StringVar()
n2 = StringVar()
def result() :
   if combo1.get() == "Addition" :
     Res = int(n1.get())+int(n2.get())
     print("You have selected Addition, Answer is : ", Res)
   else :
     Res = int(n1.get())-int(n2.get())
     print("You have selected Subtraction, Answer is : ", Res)
combo1 = Combobox(window,width=50)
lbl1 = Label(window,text='  Select   Work Type :').grid(row=3,column=1,pady=10)
combo1['values']= ("Addition","Subtraction")
combo1.current(0)
combo1.grid(row=3,column=2)
lbl2 = Label(window,text='Enter First Number   : ').grid(row=4,column=1)
txt2 = Entry(window,textvariable=n1,width=20).grid(row=4,column=2,pady=5)
lbl3 = Label(window,text='Enter Second Number  : ').grid(row=5,column=1)
txt3 = Entry(window,textvariable=n2,width=20).grid(row=5,column=2,pady=5)
but1 = Button(window,text="Result",command=result).grid(row=10,column=2)
txt4 = Text(window,width=30,height=15).grid(row=15,column=2)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: There's no simple way to do it, but the `errorwindow.py` module shown in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49016673/355230) to another question makes it relatively easy.

Comment: You can use `txt4.insert(...)` to replace the `print(...)` statements.  But first change `txt4 = Text(...).grid(...)` to `txt4 = Text(...)` and `txt4.grid(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to Align the text from an entry you can use the keyword "justify" [Entry documentation](http://tkinter.fdex.eu/doc/entw.html)

If you want to display information inside a Label, you can use the keyword "text" [Label documentation](http://tkinter.fdex.eu/doc/labw.html#label)

You can use both keyword inside your definition

```
txt2 = Entry(window, text=n1, width=20, justify="left")
```

or you can use them afterward (for a dynamic use)

```
lbl2 = Label(window,text='Enter First Number   : ').grid(row=4,column=1)
lbl2["text"] = "text has been changed"
```

Note : There is other way to justify your content so be sure to check "anchor" keyword from Label or Entry but also "sticky" from the grid function