# How to write terminal output to a .txt file as a log

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, logfile

I know this question has been asked a lot but i have not really found a suitable solution for my problem.
I have tried to implement

```
python myScript.py 2> errorlog.txt > logfile.txt
```

which also works but I don't want to run my code again since it should be implemented inside a GUI where when running it will execute some simulations and semi heavy calculations and I want the terminal output to be written/logged when you exit the GUI.

Hope someone can help me on my way.

Comment: Use the `script` command.

Comment: Why is there terminal output if you have a GUI?

Comment: Im fairly new to this, what script command? well if any errors occur while running the code from the GUI they will be shown in the terminal.

Comment: IMO a GUI app shouldn't need a terminal (although you might want to use one while developing it). See the `errorwindow3k.py` module in my answer to the question [Display the output of the program on GUI with tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977473/display-the-output-of-the-program-on-gui-with-tkinter).

Comment: Here's the [linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) for the `script` command.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply i will test that out.