# how to add windows command prompt in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, cmd

I have been trying to find any way to add command prompt in TKinter gui. So, please any one can help me.

```
`from Tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()
cmd= Frame(root, width = 400, height = 200)

cmd.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
wid = cmd.winfo_id()
os.system('cmd -into %d -geometry 80x20 -sb -e python &' % wid)

root.mainloop()`
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: You don't just want to redirect standard output, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect command line results to a tkinter GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665566/redirect-command-line-results-to-a-tkinter-gui)

Comment: There are many many threads talking about this same topic. This should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't think it a duplicate because it sounds like the OP wants a command console which runs in a tkinter window.